# Spring oauth2 specify protected and unprotected resources

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented oauth2 in my spring MVC web app. Now Ive protected and unprotected resources like all my webservices and Accounts (for password reset, email validation etc). My current spring security is blocking all requests with access token even though I specified Accounts to be access fully. Could someone correct how to define protected and un-protected resources.

Web config

```
<!-- Spring Root -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>portal</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- <init-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>portal</param-value> 
        Modify this one to get clean URL without portal by plain "/" </init-param> -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

oAuth2 Web security

```
  <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
  <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
         <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
         <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
         <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
          <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
   </http>

   <http pattern="/Accounts" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
          <intercept-url pattern="/Accounts" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
          <anonymous enabled="true"/>
          <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
          <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
          <!-- <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
          <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/> -->
  </http>

   <!-- Protected resources -->
   <http pattern="/**"
  create-session="never"
  entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
          <anonymous enabled="false"/>
          <intercept-url pattern="/**"
               access="ROLE_USER"/>
          <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
               before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
          <access-denied-handler
        ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
 </http>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding /API/ControllerName to all my request mappings and changed the protected resources to /API/**

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value = "/API/ProductManagement")
 public class ProductManagementController extends BaseController {
    //Implementation
 }
```

oAuth2 web security

```
<http pattern="/Accounts" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
      <intercept-url pattern="/Accounts" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
      <anonymous enabled="false"/>
      <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
      <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
      <!-- <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
      <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/> -->
</http>

<!-- Protected resources -->
<http pattern="/API/**"
  create-session="never"
  entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
       <anonymous enabled="false"/>
       <intercept-url pattern="/**"
               access="ROLE_USER"/>
       <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
               before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
       <access-denied-handler
        ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>
```